# UIPickerView with custom buttons in iphone

Tags: iphone, button, uipickerview, addition

I need a custom picker with single component and want to add buttons adjacent to component it. Can anybody help??

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a custom view with buttons over the picker view.

Comment: Can we add a subview to picker